# Can not use @change function in v-text-field which is dynamically rendered

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I defined the change function of Text field which is dynamically rendered.
But got error.
`"[Vue warn]: Property or method 'handleChange' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...`

Is this a bug of Vuetify or Am I wrong?

This is the reproduction link.
https://codepen.io/plsdev89/pen/ZEWKEex

```
<v-col cols="12" sm="6" v-for="item in items">
   <v-text-field
      :label="item"
      @change="handleChange(item)"
   ></v-text-field>
</v-col>

method: {
  handleChange(item) {
    console.log(`${item} was changed`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are writting wrong `method`, is `methods`

you have to use

```js
methods: {
    handleChange(item) {
       console.log(`${item} was changed`)
     }
}
```